# Doubts about a Quotient group of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

Consider the subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $(9,1)$ and $(1,4)$.

1. Is $H=\{(9r + t,r + 4t) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \ |\ r,t \in \mathbb{Z}\}$?
2. I think that the order of $(\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}) / H$ is infinite, is it so?
3. Is $(\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}) / H$ isomorphic to a well-know group?

Comment: The description in 1) is correct, although not extremely helpful as it is. As to 2), your expectations I am afraid to say are deceived. In general, given a morphism $f \colon \mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{Z}^n$ of abelian groups, the index $\left(\mathbb{Z}^n \colon \mathrm{Im}f\right)$ is equal to $|\mathrm{det}f|$ -- the absolute value of the determinant of $f$ -- when this latter determinant is nonzero and is equal to $\aleph_0$ when $f$ has $0$ determinant.

Comment: Is there other helpful description?

Comment: Perhaps you could use Smith normal form... but I don't know if you're familiar with it

Comment: I think the description in 1 is entirely fine as it is. Why would you say it's unhelpful?

Comment: @John Mars It is not a description of $H$ itself you should be pursuing, but rather a different description for the endomorphism whose image $H$ occurs as. In more explicit terms, you need to consult the Smith normal form of square matrices over $\mathbb{Z}$ (more generally over any PID), together with the theory of invariant factors of a finitely generated subgroup of a free abelian subgroup.

Comment: @AntonioFicarra I am not familiar with it... but I suppose that there is a isomorphism between H and some group of matrices, is it wrong?

Comment: @Arthur Let me emphasise the nuance that it isn't *very* helpful. A manual approach such as the one you suggested in your answer will of course shed light on the answer, but it doesn't necessarily reveal the whole generality of the phenomenon.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ I am quite certain my approach can be used in general to decide that a quotient of $\Bbb Z^n$ is finite. It's difficult to use that method to conclude that the quotient is infinite, and it doesn't tell you how large it is if it is finite, just an upper bound. But that's entirely fine in this case, as nothing more is asked for.

Comment: @Arthur I would make the comment that your approach does not appear to be systematic enough to apply itself to the full generality of cases. For instance, how do you handle the case of dimension $3$ rather than $2$?

Comment: @ΑΘΩ If $H$ has three linearly independent elements (which can be determined with a determinant, but can often enough be done faster), finding an element with non-zero first component and the two others $0$, is a matter of solving two equations with two unknowns, then possibly scaling. Next, finding an element with non-zero second component and zero otherwise is even easier, as you already have the previous $(a,0,0)$ vector to help you. After that, the third one is almost trivial. It's not optimal, but it is more elementary than the other suggestions here.

Comment: (And also, pointing out that this is possible without needing to go through the actual calculations is, in my opinion, a faster proof of finiteness than introducing more general machinery. More general machinery is better introduced when methods like mine start to become a real hassle and/or actually impossible.)

Comment: @Arthur You are right, of course. It is ultimately a matter of approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}9&1\\1&4\end{bmatrix}
whose image as a map $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$ is the group $H$. We can perform automorphisms (given by invertible matrices over $\mathbb Z$, realized by row and column operations) to obtain the matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&35\end{bmatrix}
Thus, the group $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z/H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/35$.

Edit: (more detail)
Note that we can view elements of $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$ as column matrices
\begin{bmatrix}r\\t\end{bmatrix} and we can view a $2\times 2$ matrix over $\mathbb Z$ as a homomorphism $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$ by matrix multiplication:
$$\begin{bmatrix}9&1\\1&4\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}r\\t\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}9r + t\\r+4t\end{bmatrix}$$
This explains how to represent $H$ as the image of this matrix.
Now, note that, by easy algebra, if I apply an automorphism of $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$ before or after the given matrix, the resulting quotients will be isomorphic (this is basic group theory):
Given an isomorphism $G\to G'$, and a subgroup $H$ with image $H'$, there is an induced isomorphism $G/H \to G'/H'$. Now, composition of homomorphisms corresponds to matrix multiplication (you can check this easily). So, we can multiply on the left and the right of the above matrix by any matrices that are invertible over $\mathbb Z$, and thus represent automorphisms of $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$. Now, observe that:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}1&-8\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}9&1\\1&4\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}1&31\\0&1\end{bmatrix} =$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}1&-31\\1&4\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}1&31\\0&1\end{bmatrix} =$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-31\\0&35\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}1&31\\0&1\end{bmatrix} =$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&35\end{bmatrix}$$
Using the interpretation above, the image of the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&35\end{bmatrix}
is all column matrices of the form:
\begin{bmatrix}r\\35t\end{bmatrix}
and the quotient of this subgroup is $0\oplus \mathbb Z/35 = \mathbb Z/35$.

Further edit (yet more detail):
So, the idea is that the subgroup $H$ is the image of a homomorphism, so say we have a homomorphism: $f:G \to G$, and then we apply an isomorphism $i: G\to G$ before $f$, then we get the composition $fi: G\to G$, since $i$ is onto, the image of this map is equal to the image of $f$, and so we have an isomorphism (equality in this case) $G/fi(G) = G/f(G)$. On the other side, if we apply $i$ after $f$, then we observe that $if(G)$ is the image of $f(G)$ under $i$, and therefore we get an induced isomorphism $G/f(G) \to G/if(G)$. By iterating this, we can pre and post-compose the homomorphism $f$ by any number of isomorphisms and we will get an induced isomorphism on the quotient of the image. In this case, the matrix:\begin{bmatrix}9&1\\1&4\end{bmatrix}  is the homomorphism $f$, and the isomorphisms are given by the invertible matrices I multiplied by on the left and right. You should verify that matrix multiplication corresponds to composition of homomorphisms.

Comment: I'am a beginner in group theory, can you give me a explanation of this process?

Comment: It seems that the product of these matrices represent a homomorphism, so How you apply this:  Given an $isomorphism$ G→G′, and a subgroup H with image H′, there is an induced isomorphism G/H→G′/H′?

Comment: I added some more detail.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yeah, that's one way to describe $H$
2. Note that $H$ contains $(35,0)$ (set $r=4$ and $t=-1$) and $(0,35)$ (set $r=-1$ and $t=9$). So any element in $\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z/H$ has at least one representative $(a,b)$ with $0\leq a,b<35$.

Comment: Can you give me an explanation of 2.?

Comment: @JohnMars In what way? Which part of it do you struggle with?

Comment: I am agree with the first part, but I don't find a justification to the conclusion (So any element in Z⊕Z/H has at least one representative (a,b) with 0≤a,b<35.)?

Comment: @JohnMars If we have an element in the quotient group with representative $(a,b)$, then $(a,b)+(x,y)$ represents the same element for any $(x,y)\in H$. You can use this repeatedly, together with $(35,0),(0,35)\in H$, to find a representative of the same element with first component between $0$ and $35$, and second component between $0$ and $35$. Just add a suitable number of $(35,0),(-35,0),(0,35)$ or $(0,-35)$.

Comment: @John Mars By virtue of Arthur's observation, it follows that $35\mathbb{Z} \times 35\mathbb{Z} \leqslant H$, so that the quotient $(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z})/H$ is a homomorphic image of $(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z})/(35\mathbb{Z} \times 35\mathbb{Z})$. This latter quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{35}^2$ and thus finite, so consequently so will be the quotient $(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z})/H$.

Comment: @John Mars or more simply put, consider the remainders by division with 35 for each component of an arbitrary element $(m, n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$.